# How to run some programs which require `source ~/.bashrc` and to be launched inside tmux with upstart?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, tmux, upstart

I have some programs which require `source ~/.bashrc` and should be launched inside tmux with upstart.
So I've wrote the following test programs and it works when I manually start these daemons by `initctl start xxx`, but it doesn't at boot-time.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Does anyone have a solution?

#### test programs

- 3 test conf scripts

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ cat /etc/init/start-tmux.conf
description "tmux daemon"

start on started network-manager
stop on runlevel [!2345]
umask 022
nice -5

script
     sudo -iu eisoku /bin/bash -i -c 'source ~/.bashrc && bash ~/Desktop/util/start-tmux.bash' &
     watch -n 100 ls
end script
```

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ cat /etc/init/test-a.conf 
description "test a daemon"

start on started start-tmux
stop on stopped start-tmux
umask 022

script
     sudo -iu eisoku /bin/bash -i -c "source ~/Desktop/util/tmux-patch.bash && tmux-newwindow test-a htop" &
     watch -n 100 ls
end script
```

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ cat /etc/init/test-b.conf 
description "test b daemon"

start on started start-tmux
stop on stopped start-tmux
umask 022

script
     sudo -iu eisoku /bin/bash -i -c "source ~/Desktop/util/tmux-patch.bash && tmux-newwindow test-b top" &
     watch -n 100 ls
end script
```

- util scripts

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ cat ~/Desktop/util/start-tmux.bash 
#!/bin/bash    
SESSION_NAME=`hostname`
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION_NAME -n tmp
```

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ cat ~/Desktop/util/tmux-patch.bash 
#!/bin/bash
tmux-newwindow() {
    if [ `tmux list-windows | grep " $1 " | cut -d' ' -f2` ]; then
        echo $1 "already exists"
    else
        tmux new-window -k -n $1 -t `hostname`
        tmux send-keys -t `hostname`:$1 ${@:2} C-m
    fi
}

tmux-killwindow() {
    if [ `tmux list-windows | grep " $1 " | cut -d' ' -f2` ]; then
        tmux kill-window -t $1
    else
        echo $i "not exists"
    fi
}
```

#### result

```bash
eisoku@local-PC:~$ ssh eisoku@server
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-26-generic x86_64)
eisoku@server:~$ sudo reboot
```

After reboot,

```bash
eisoku@local-PC:~$ ssh eisoku@server 
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-26-generic x86_64)
eisoku@server:~$ tmux list-windows
0: tmp [80x23] [layout b85e,80x23,0,0] (active)
eisoku@server:~$
eisoku@server:~$ initctl status start-tmux 
start-tmux start/running, process 1030
eisoku@server:~$ initctl status test-a
test-a start/running, process 1033
eisoku@server:~$ initctl status test-b
test-b start/running, process 1031
```

test-a and test-b seem not to be worked as I had expected while the status of the daemons is running.

However, it works when I manually start these daemons

```bash
eisoku@server:~$ sudo initctl restart test-a
test-a start/running, process 3369
eisoku@server:~$ sudo initctl restart test-b
test-b start/running, process 3461
eisoku@server:~$ tmux list-windows
0: tmp [80x23] [layout b85e,80x23,0,0]
1: test-a [80x23] [layout b85e,80x23,0,0]
2: test-b [80x23] [layout b85e,80x23,0,0] (active)
```

Comment: `~` doesn't have the value you are expecting in those circumstances. Don't use it. Use an explicit path.

Comment: Thank your for your reply, but I don't think so because I use interactive shell like this ``sudo -iu my-name /bin/bash -i -c 'command'``.

Comment: Try using `$HOME` then. `~` expansion is different than variable expansion.

Comment: Both ``~`` and ``$HOME`` work when I start the daemon by hand as I posted, and they don't work when they are started by init system automatically.

Comment: If you redirect stdout and stderr from the shell snippets in test-a and test-b to a log file what do you see from the bootup attempts?

Comment: I see the the log files with ``sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/test-a.log`` and the result is ``install: cannot create regular file `/dev/shm/byobu-eisoku-G2FL45ZP/printscreen': File exists``.

Comment: Sometimes the job script works, and sometimes doesn't. The log message like ``install: cannot create regular file `/dev/shm/byobu-eisoku-xxxx/printscreen': File exists`` shows up only when it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like collisions with something in your byobu configuration then.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my own problem. It is because Upstart run jobs in parallel and Upstart tries to start test-a job just after upstart starts start-tmux job so that tmux, which is launched by start-tmux job in this case, is not completely launched.

I can solve it by using pre-start to wait for tmux to be launched and letting test-b job chain to test-a like this.

---

```
eisoku@server:~$ cat /etc/init/test-a.conf 
description "test a daemon"

start on started start-tmux
stop on stopped start-tmux
umask 022

pre-start script
     /bin/sleep 1
end script

script
     sudo -iu eisoku /bin/bash -i -c "source ~/Desktop/util/tmux-patch.bash && tmux-newwindow test-a htop" &
     watch -n 100 ls
end script
```

---

```
eisoku@server:~$ cat /etc/init/test-b.conf 
description "test b daemon"

start on started test-a
stop on stopped start-tmux
umask 022

pre-start script
     /bin/sleep 1
end script

script
     sudo -iu eisoku /bin/bash -i -c "source ~/Desktop/util/tmux-patch.bash && tmux-newwindow test-b top" &
     watch -n 100 ls
end script
```